# Changing template for event/contribution forms

Tags: wordpress

The wordpress site is setup with a 2 column template as the default. But this doesn't work for event/contribution forms. If I forget to set the template to full width I get a sidebar. If I set the template to full width, I get the sidebar inserted at the bottom of the forms pages. I think there is a way to set the default template for a form but can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following snippet to your theme `functions.php` replacing `page.php` with the template you want to use.

**Note:** you have to be using >= v4.6 of CiviCRM in order to use this.

```
add_filter('civicrm_basepage_template', 'my_base_template');

function my_base_template($template){
    return 'page.php';
}
```